# How do you set a Link so that it opens in a new tab or window in Google App Maker?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

In my Google App Maker application, whenever a user clicks on a Link, it causes the href link to open in the same window as the application. This causes a problem because the user has to click back in order to access the application again. Is there any way to set the link such that when a user clicks on it (without right click > open new tab), the page opens in a new tab/window? Thanks.

Comment: <a target='_blank'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 
`window.open('www.your_link.com','_blank');`

Answer (score 2):

In the app maker property editor for the link widget set the target property to _blank[image: Example]